# GUI - Linux - C - how click events are managed?

Tags: c, linux, user-interface, events

#### Context:

Reading some GUI libraries on Linux 64.

I've always used libraries (or done headless applications). Now, it is time to move on and complete my understanding.

#### Question:

I am not sure how the system knows when one clicks a button on a gui app.

It seems that poll/select/epoll helps but I don't get the whole picture.

Here is what I think:
When the gui is created, it knows where the buttons pixels are, so it attaches each of them to an event handler (epoll...), OR just one callback to react to a click in this app.

When I click a button, epoll calls the callback for this application which manages the click events. the callback iterates the list to find the button.

Of course, there are optimisations, like dividing the screen in multiple squares for example and many other things.

But, am I correct ? is this the logic under the hood ? Is X11 more involved ?

Thanks

Comment: Why would GUI be a Linux issue? It is not Windows. Just read about the various GUI systems on Linux. They are OSS, so you are welcome to read the code and other information to be found (there is a lot). If you have any specific question, feel free to ask, but please understand this is not a tutorial site.

Comment: huumm... is a yes or no a tutorial answer ? it is about the big picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after your comment: I'll bite:

**No**, you are not right.

But how does that increase your knowledge now?